# Get Text Content of list item

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two list items in my html page.I would like to access the "text content" of the "first list item" present in the "first unordered list".I need to do it with javascript and not jquery.This is what i tried but does'nt seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>dom</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 function createcontent(){    
      var val = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = val;
    }

 </script>
</head>

<body onload="createcontent();">
<ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>cured</li>
    <li>eggs</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>cabbage</li>
    <li>califlower</li>
    <li>apple</li>
</ul>

<p id="content"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `childNodes` includes text and comment nodes. The whitespace between your tags constitutes text nodes as well – and therefor `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].childNodes[0]` is _not_ referring to the first LI element here.

Comment: @CBroe yes.my mistake.any way to calculate what is the child number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>dom</title>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 function createcontent(){    
      var val = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].children[0].innerText;
   alert(val);
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = val;
    }

 </script>
</head>

<body onload="createcontent();">
<ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>cured</li>
    <li>eggs</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>cabbage</li>
    <li>califlower</li>
    <li>apple</li>
</ul>

<p id="content"></p>
</body>

</html>
```